# Can I use both paired and unpaired t test in one study?

Tags: anova, manova

Is it possible to use both unpaired and paired t test in one study since I plan to both test the effect (pretest & posttest) in each participant and compare the results between the non-randomized treatment and control group? Or what would be the appropriate statistical treatment?

Comment: How are the subjects selected for each group? Pairing seems to make sense since the individual differences removes the skill effects of the students.

Comment: The answer to the general question in the title is "yes, under appropriate circumstances". The more specific question in the body would possibly require more information. When you say "non-randomized treatment" do you mean that assignment of people to the treatment or control groups was not random? That could present some problems for you (though the existence of the pre-test results allows you to at least remove one potential issue. What are your hypotheses? ... ctd

Comment: ctd... If there could be a difference between groups on pre-test (and if you don't have random assignment you probably do) you'd want to adjust your treatment comparison for that.  However, you have other substantive problems. What if there are two kinds of people in your population, one which is like the other on pre-test but differently to treatment than the other, and your non-random assignment has resulted in most of one of those two groups being assigned to one of the treatment groups and hardly any to the other. Depending on which group it was you could have very different conclusions

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, rather I will have non randomized selection of participants since I will identify the centers while inwill do a randomized assignment if they will be under treatment (where i will employ an intervention to mental health professionals) or control group. My hypothesis is that mental health professionals will have a significant difference on wellbeing after participating in a clinical supervision program...ctd

Comment: To clarify, what i can infer is that it would be risky to inmediately decide to do group comparison since I do not have pretest data yet & i can later decide yo adjust nybtreatment comparison? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I won't say it is never appropriate to do so, but I think it is inappropriate in your case.

The paired t-test you have is fine. But using an independent samples t-test to compare the groups wastes a lot of information and ignores the dependency in the data.

I suggest a multilevel model with "group" as one IV.